# Creating Target Values for Training Data - Neural Networks

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I've been given some bacteria data and I'm supposed to use neural networks to classify the bacteria as belonging to Group A or Group B.

The bacteria dataset I've been given looks like this. There are 18 .mat Matlab datasets which are as follows: A1.mat, A2.mat, A3.mat, A4.mat, A5.mat, A6.mat, A7.mat, A8.mat, A9.mat, B1.mat, B2.mat, B3.mat, B4.mat, B5.mat, B6.mat, B7.mat, B8.mat, B9.mat.

Each of these Matlab dataset consists of a 2510 x 2 matrix. The first column is the time information and the second column is some bacteria information. I extracted only the bacteria information in column 2 between indices 900 and 1200. That was the portion I needed for my analysis. This yielded a 209 x 1 matrix.

I went on to create my input data as an 209 x 18 matrix, i.e., extracting data between 900 and 1200 indices for each of the datasets and putting everything together.

My goal in this project is to classify bacteria as belonging to Group A or Group B. From this point on, I'm at a loss on how to get the target values I need to feed into the neural network. Do I need additional information in order to proceed? That is, should the dataset have also contained target information as well? Any help at this point would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have 418 total exemplars, each with 9 features, with 209 belonging to Group A and 209 belonging to group B. For what it's worth, you'd typically want to have many, many more exemplars to train a neural network.

Instead of thinking of your classification problem as A or B, think about it as 'A' or 'not A.' So exemplars belonging to Group A have a target value of 1, and exemplars belonging to group B have a target value of 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and insight. I considered 418 examples lso. But won't the combined features for the two groups still be 9 features? Let me explain: My reasoning is that, you get 418 examples by concatenating the 209 from the two groups. Each of them have 9 features so I thinking it should be a 418 x 9 matrix. What do you think? Please explain why you think is 418 x 18. Thanks again for responding to my question.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry about that. Updated the answer. Now you can present each of the 418 exemplars to your network, and update your weights using error based on the target (0 or 1) of each exemplar as it is presented.

Comment: Thanks so much. I decided to use 418 examples and 9 features while I waited for your reply. I also used the 'A' (1) and 'not A' (0) target values. And I'm getting good results. Thanks so much. You've really helped me. Thanks ohruunuruus!